# Refresing a route with more than one '/' gives errors in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, express, routes

Routes like `/home`, `/profile`, and even `/` work perfectly when pressing browser refresh button on them, because then, the server sends the default .html and angular files (because of the server code below), and these angular files then handle the current url.

My problem occurs when I press refresh on routes with more than one `/` (which is necessary when using, say, route parameters), like `/manage/users`, `/user/12345678`...etc.

And then, jQuery throws this weird error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`, and then Bootstrap starts complaining about not getting jQuery, and page looks crappy without the makeup ... and so on.

Just to be clear, when I visit routes with more than one `/`, by using Angular's own router (using `$state.go('/manage/users')`, `<ui-sref='profile'>` etc.), this problem (obviously) doesn't occur, because then Angular has already been loaded to handle that url.

But when I refresh the page, since there is no Angular to handle that route, browser asks the server for the route, and apparently, `/*` in Express can't handle this route too.

I serve the .html file from my server by:

```
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    // Just send the index.html for other files to support HTML5Mode
    res.render('index.html');
});
```

after handling all the API routes. The index.html (hopefully) loads all the angular files afterwards.

Is there something like:

```
app.all('**/*', function(req, res, next) { ... });
```

... to render html at any route, with any number of `/`s? Or some kind of Regex maybe?

TIA

Comment: are you using html5Mode?

Comment: @QoP Yep, using $locationProvider.html5Mode(true)

Comment: @QoP OK! Setting $locationProvider.html5Mode(false) magically solves the problem! But puts `#!` (hashbang) before the app route. I need to remove that too, because I'm implementing Facebook share, and apparently, it doesn't work with hashbangs

Comment: When you had html5(true), did you set the base?

Comment: Got it! I just moved `<base href="/"> above all the script tags in the HTML, and it God-knows-how worked!! **Thanks alot** @QoP :)

Comment: gonna post it as the answer so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the base in your "head"

```
<head>
  <base href="/">
  ...
</head>
```